# How do I test an element that is outside the enzyme wrapper?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using `Jest` and `Enzyme` to do unit tests.

In my test.js file I have

```
let wrapper = mount(<app />
```

My test clicks a button in the wrapper

```
wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')
```

and the component renders a modal that is outside the wrapper.

I need to get a reference to the modal so I can simulate a click on a button in it. I can get a reference to the modal through `document.body.children`, but I can't do anything with it.

How do I use enzyme to test an element that is outside the the rendered wrapper?

Comment: Can you fire a normal DOM event on the button to simulate the click? There's a [helper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) function for this that should work if you use `document.querySelector('..').click()`.

Comment: @ivarni  no, when I run test, not in the browser environment. I can't use any web API

Comment: Ah right. We run ours in jsdom but then we don't use Jest. If your component has a ref to the modal can you access it via [instance()](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.md)? I'm not sure if it would work but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score -2):

You can test ButtonOnclik with one defined State in your React App

**In your Component**

```
state={
    data: 'first State',
};

render(){
return (<div>
     <button onClick={(e) => this.setState({data: 'second State'})}>Test</button>

</div>
}
```

**In Test you can use Enzyme or only Jest**

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Name Your Component/>);

it('test button', () => {
        expect(wrapper.state().data).toBe('first State');
        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
        expect(wrapper.state().data).toBe('second State')
    });
```

Hope its helpful for you :)

Comment: It looks like you misunderstanding my meaning,Later I will edit my problem,I think it will be helpful